# Java Array change value for half of half etc

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So I have a method that takes in a size of an array. My method makes half the array 0's.

```
int [] arrary2 = new int[arraySize];
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize/2; i++){
    arr2[i] = 0;
}
//do rest of code?
return array2;
```

How do I make the half of the last half my array into 1's and so on.
For example an array of size 14, but the array size could be any size?

[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rough algorithm:

- Calculate half what's left to do (be careful with odd / even)
- Fill that with the current value
- Repeat

Sample code:

```
public static int[] createArray(int size)
{
    int[] array = new int[size];
    int half = (size / 2) + (size % 2);
    int index = half;
    int value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i == index) {
            half = (half / 2) + (half % 2);
            index += half;
            value++;
        }
        array[i] = value;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Sample output:

```
15 => 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3
14 => 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    static int[] createArray(int size) {
        int[] result = new int[size];

        int limit = (size + 1) / 2;

        int start = 0, value = 0, idx = 0;

        do {
            for (int i = start; i < start + limit && idx < size; ++i)
                result[idx++] = value;

            start += limit;
            limit = (limit + 1) / 2;
            ++value;
        } while (idx < size);

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] result = createArray(70);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }
}
```

A couple of tests:

```
14 => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
70 => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this keep track of where you want the input value to change, the input value and also how many inserts you want to perform until the next change.

```
        int[] arrary2 = new int[arraySize];
        int currentEndPoint = (arraySize / 2) + (arraySize % 2);
        int endPointIncrement = currentEndPoint;
        int currentInputValue = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        {
            if (i == currentEndPoint - 1)
            {
                currentInputValue++;
                endPointIncrement = (endPointIncrement / 2) + (endPointIncrement % 2);
                currentEndPoint = currentEndPoint + endPointIncrement;
            }
            arrary2[i] = currentInputValue;
        }
        return arrary2;
```

Hope this helps